# XQuery v3 - comparing two values of two different files

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I assume, this can be solved using grouping, but as a beginner in XQuery, I am not quite able to write a functioning query. 
I am using eXist-db, with `XQuery version 3.`

I have two XML documents. The first one containing records that look like this :

```
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="COMPLT16"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QLABEL" Value="Completers of Week 16 Population Flag"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="2" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="COMPLT24"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QLABEL" Value="Completers of Week 24 Population Flag"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="3" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="COMPLT8"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QLABEL" Value="Completers of Week 8 Population Flag"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="4" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="EFFICACY"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="5" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="ITT"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QLABEL" Value="Intent to Treat Population Flag"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="6" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="SAFETY"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QLABEL" Value="Safety Population Flag"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="7" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1023"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="EFFICACY"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QLABEL" Value="Efficacy Population Flag"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="8" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1023"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="ITT"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QLABEL" Value="Intent to Treat Population Flag"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="9" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1023"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="SAFETY"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QLABEL" Value="Safety Population Flag"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1198" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="RACE1"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1199" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="RACE2"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="SUPPDM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1200" >
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1023"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="SUPPDM.QNAM" Value="RACE1"/>
</ItemGroupData>
```

The focus is on the last three records (`‘RACEx’`).

The second document has the following records (with unique records, each has a different `USUBJID`).

```
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1" >
<ItemData ItemOID="DM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1015"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="DM.RACE" Value="Multiple"/>
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="2" >
<ItemData ItemOID="DM.USUBJID" Value="01-701-1023"/>
<ItemData ItemOID="DM.RACE" Value="Multiple"/>
</ItemGroupData>
```

As you can see, `SUPPDM` has several records with the same `USUBJID` but can have several `QNAM` values. 
I want to check, whether `QNAM` for a certain `USUBJID` is “`RACEx`”, when `DM.RACE is Multiple`.

I tried to write an XQuery and it actually kind of works BUT the return somehow does not return the value of `RACE`.. can you please help me?

Here is my XQuery (in the beginning, I declared my variables which I get from another Metadata XML file)  :

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace def = "http://www.cdisc.org/ns/def/v2.0";
declare namespace odm="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3";
declare namespace data="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/Dataset-XML/v1.0";
declare namespace xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

let $base := '/db/mydataset/'
let $define := 'define_2_0.xml'

(: get the SUPPDM dataset :)
let $suppdmdataset := doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemGroupDef[@Name='SUPPDM']
let $suppdmdatasetname := $suppdmdataset/def:leaf/@xlink:href
let $suppdmdatasetlocation := concat($base,$suppdmdatasetname)

(: get the DM dataset :)
let $dmdataset := doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemGroupDef[@Name='DM']
let $dmdatasetname := $dmdataset/def:leaf/@xlink:href
let $dmdatasetlocation := concat($base,$dmdatasetname)

(:get the USUBJID in DM :)
let $dmusubjidoid := (
    for $a in doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemDef[@Name='USUBJID']/@OID 
    where $a = doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemGroupDef[@Name='DM']/odm:ItemRef/@ItemOID
    return $a
)
(:get the USUBJID in SUPPDM :)
let $suppdmusubjidoid := (
    for $a in doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemDef[@Name='USUBJID']/@OID 
    where $a = doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemGroupDef[@Name='SUPPDM']/odm:ItemRef/@ItemOID
    return $a
)
(: get the OID of RACE in DM dataset :)
let $raceoid := (
    for $a in doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemDef[@Name='RACE']/@OID 
    where $a = doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemGroupDef[@Name='DM']/odm:ItemRef/@ItemOID
    return $a
)
(: get the OID of QNAM in SUPPDM :)
let $qnamoid := (
    for $a in doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemDef[@Name='QNAM']/@OID 
    where $a = doc(concat($base,$define))//odm:ItemGroupDef[@Name='SUPPDM']/odm:ItemRef/@ItemOID
    return $a
)
(:substring(QNAM,1,4) = „RACE“ :)

(:we are searching through the subjects in DM that have the value "Multiple" in RACE :)

for $record in doc($dmdatasetlocation)//odm:ItemGroupData[odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$raceoid and upper-case(@Value)='MULTIPLE']]
(:or for $record in doc($suppdmdatasetlocation)//odm:ItemGroupData[odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$qnamoid]]/starts-with(@Value,"RACE") :)

    let $recnum := $record/@data:ItemGroupDataSeq

(: Get the DM USUBJID value :)
let $dmusubjidvalue := $record/odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$dmusubjidoid]/@Value

(: now get the value of QNAM in SUPPDM for the subject with the corresponding USUBJID - it should be "RACE1", RACE2 or ... "RACEn"; principally it should start with 'RACE' :)
let $qnamvalue := (
    for $a in doc($suppdmdatasetlocation)//odm:ItemGroupData[odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$suppdmusubjidoid and @Value=$dmusubjidvalue]]
    let $b := doc($suppdmdatasetlocation)//odm:ItemGroupData[odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$qnamoid]]/upper-case(@Value)
    where (starts-with($b, 'RACE'))
    return $a
)

(:now check, whether the value QNAM starts with 'RACE' :)

(:  where not(starts-with($qnamvalue, "RACE")):)

    return <warning recordnumber="{data($recnum)}">Invalid value for QNAM in dataset {data($suppdmdatasetname)} - Label={data($qnamvalue)}. => RACE in {data($dmdatasetlocation)} for subject {data($dmusubjidvalue)} is 'Multiple', so QNAM should be in (RACE1, RACE2,... RACEn). If RACE is 'Multiple', additional information has to be added to the Supplemental Qualifier dataset of DM  (SUPPDM)       </warning>
```

I am not sure about the `WHERE` expression. Unfortunately, my output looks like this:
"Invalid value for `QNAM` in dataset `suppdm.xml` Label=. =>"
The XQuery does not return `$qnamvalue`… this is always empty.

(update 12/05/2015)
Here I post the new XQuery based on the suggestion of adamretter!

```
for $record in doc($dmdatasetlocation)//odm:ItemGroupData
let $recnum := $record/@data:ItemGroupDataSeq

(: get value of usubjid :)
let $dmusubjidvalue := $record//odm:ItemData[@ItemOID=$dmusubjidoid]/@Value

(:check, whether this usubjid has a record in SUPPDM that has QNAM in 'RACEx' :)
let $multiple-usubjid :=
    not(empty(doc("$dmdatasetlocation")//odm:ItemGroupData[odm:ItemData[@ItemOID =$dmusubjidoid][@Value =$dmusubjidvalue]][odm:ItemData[@ItemOID eq $raceoid][@Value eq "Multiple"]]
    ))
return
(:it will return give a return if there exists a usubjid that has a QNAM that matches RACE :)
    if($multiple-usubjid) then
        doc($suppdmdatasetlocation)//odm:ItemGroupData[odm:ItemData[@ItemOID = $suppdmusubjidoid][@Value = $dmusubjidvalue]][odm:ItemData[@ItemOID =$qnamoid]
               [fn:matches(@Value, "RACE[0-9]+")]]
        else( 
 <warning rule="SPC_DM_RACE_01" rulelastupdate="2015-02-10" recordnumber="{data($recnum)}">Invalid value for QNAM in dataset {data($suppdmdatasetname)} - Label={data($multiple-usubjid)}. => RACE in {data

($dmdatasetlocation)} for subject {data($dmusubjidvalue)} is 'Multiple', so QNAM should be in (RACE1, RACE2,... RACEn). If RACE is 'Multiple', additional information has to be added to the Supplemental Qualifier dataset of DM  (SUPPDM)       

</warning>
```

I quite understood the expressions, but how can I retrieve the right `QNAM` value with `RACE` in it? The Query doesn't work the way I want it to and somehow I get all records returned from `DM`.

At least, I get a value for `multiple-usubjid` (False or True) but I want to recieve `QNAM` value for the specific `USUBJID` that has `RACE` in it.
I am a real beginner and I don't quite know what I have to put into the else expression, or how I have to "reorganize" the query.

Again, thank you for your help!
Christiane

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a simple join across the two files, although you can also do it without a join. As you really have two queries, and the second query only needs to be executed if the first query matches.

To simplify your issue I stored your two XML files into `/tmp/doc1.xml` and `/tmp/doc2.xml`, and focused on finding the nodes that you were interested in, a lot of your XQuery above is not really focused on the core problem you are experiencing. Anyway, here is my proposed solution -

```
xquery version "1.0";

(: the USUBJID you are interested in :)
declare variable $local:usubjid := "01-701-1015";

let $multiple-usubjid :=
    not(empty(
        doc("/tmp/doc2.xml")
            //ItemGroupData[ItemData[@ItemOID eq "DM.USUBJID"]
               [@Value eq $local:usubjid]][ItemData[@ItemOID eq "DM.RACE"]
               [@Value eq "Multiple"]]
    ))
return
    if($multiple-usubjid) then
        doc("/tmp/doc1.xml")
            //ItemGroupData[ItemData[@ItemOID eq "SUPPDM.USUBJID"]
               [@Value eq $local:usubjid]][ItemData[@ItemOID eq "SUPPDM.QNAM"]
               [fn:matches(@Value, "RACE[0-9]+")]]
    else()
```

Now obviously this could be extracted into a function or rewritten to be more efficient if you want to test all `USUBJID`, but hopefully it is a good starting point for discussion.

Comment: Hey @adamretter, thank you for your help, it is a good starting point adn it seems I am getting closer and closer to a solution! I updated my question and used your solution but it doesn't work yet the way I expect it to. 

I use non-local variables because I have 300 records in DM and so I try to be generic.